# Как преобразовать int в QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-faq

Существует ли функция `QString` в качестве аргумента принимающая тип **int** и возвращающая его как `QString`?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[How to convert int to QString?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3211771/564240)» [@Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366207/).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211771/how-to-convert-int-to-qstring

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Способ 1

Используйте [`QString::number()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number):

```
int i = 42;
QString s = QString::number(i);
```

---

#### Способ 2

Вы можете использовать метод `arg`:

```
QString QString::arg ( int a, int fieldWidth = 0, int base = 10, const QChar & fillChar = QLatin1Char( ' ' ) ) const
```

---

#### Способ 3

И если вы хотите использовать решение при объединении строк, забудьте об операторе `+`. Просто сделайте так:

```
// Qt 5 + C++11
auto i = 13;    
auto printable = QStringLiteral("My magic number is %1. That's all!").arg(i);

// Qt 5
int i = 13;    
QString printable = QStringLiteral("My magic number is %1. That's all!").arg(i);

// Qt 4
int i = 13;    
QString printable = QString::fromLatin1("My magic number is %1. That's all!").arg(i);
```

---

#### Способ 4

Еще один способ – использовать [QTextStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtextstream.html) и оператор `<<` примерно так же, как вы бы использовали `cout` в C++:

```
QPoint point(5,1);
QString str;
QTextStream(&str) << "Mouse click: (" << point.x() << ", " << point.y() << ").";

// OUTPUT:
// Mouse click: (5, 1).
```

Поскольку оператор `<<` переопределяется, его можно использовать для нескольких типов, не только для `int`. `QString::arg()` переопределяется, например, `arg(int a1, int a2)`, но здесь отсутствует `arg(int a1, QString a2)`, поэтому использование `QTextStream()` и оператора `<<` удобно при форматировании более длинных строк со смешанными типами.

**Предупреждение**: у вас может возникнуть желание использовать `sprintf()` для воспроизведения операторов `printf()` в C–стиле, но я рекомендую использовать `QTextStream` или `arg()`, так как они поддерживают строки в формате `Unicode`.

---

#### Способ 5

Взгляните на `QString::setNum()`.

```
int i = 10;
double d = 10.75;
QString str;
str.setNum(i);
str.setNum(d);
```

`setNum()` переопределяется множеством способов. См. Справочное описание класса `QString`.

---

#### Способ 6

Более того, для конвертации из различных форматов и в различные форматы вы можете воспользоваться `QVariant`. Для конвертации `int` в `QString` получим:

```
QVariant(3).toString();
```

Для конвертации типа `float` в `String` или `String` в `float`:

```
QVariant(3.2).toString();
QVariant("5.2").toFloat();
```

<sub>На основе ответов из вопроса «[How to convert int to QString?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3211771/564240)».</sub>

Answer (score 1):

casting a variable to a string type (приведение переменной к типу строки)

```
QString str = QString("%1").arg(x)
```

Or formatted string (Или к форматированная строка)

```
QString str = QString("x1= %1   x2= %2").arg(x1).arg(x2)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]