# Как указать количество значащих цифр после запятой при преобразовании в QString?

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу программу в Qt, на С++, для перевода значений координат из геодезической системы координат в координаты прямоугольной системы координат, во всех вычислениях мне нужна точность минимум до 8-го знака.

Вот к примеру есть такая функция для перевода градусов в радианы:

```
#include "convertorad.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

double convertToRad(double grad){
    double rad;
    rad = (grad * 3.1415926535897932) / 180;
    QString str;
    str.setNum(rad);
    qDebug() << str;
    return  rad;
}
```

Вывод `qDebug()` при `grad = 49.8344` и `grad = 36.7203` следующий:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно минимум 0.86977439, а 0.8697743902. Идеально это до 10-го знака.

Вот сама функция для перевода из геодезической системы координат в прямоугольную:

```
#include "to_rectangular_cs.h"
#include <QDebug>


QString to_rectangular_cs(double BGrad, double BMin, double BSec,
                            double LGrad, double LMin, double LSec, double h){

    BGrad = BGrad + (BMin / 60);
    BGrad = BGrad + (BSec / 3600);

    double BRad;

    BRad = convertToRad(BGrad);

    LGrad = LGrad + (LMin / 60);
    LGrad = LGrad + (LSec / 3600);

    double LRad;

    LRad = convertToRad(LGrad);


    double alpha, E, N;
    int a = 6378137;

    alpha = 1 / 298.257223563;
    E = 2 * alpha - pow(alpha, 2);
    N =  a / sqrt((1 - E * pow(sin(BRad), 2)));

    double X, Y, Z;


    X = (N + h) * (cos(BRad)) * (cos(LRad));
    Y = (N + h) * (cos(BRad)) * (sin(LRad));
    Z = (floor(((1 - E) * N + h) + 0.5)) * (sin(BRad));

    QString res, str;

    res = str.setNum(X) + " " + str.setNum(Y) + " " + str.setNum(Z);

    return res;
}
```

Строка которая возвращается этой функцией с помощью .split(" ") делится и записывается в переменную класса QStringList, а затем устанавливается в с помощью .setText() в lineEdit-ы.
Выводится с экспонентой до 5-го знака, а нужно минимум до 8-го:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519913/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-int-%d0%b2-qstring), изобилующий вариациями возможностей. Пусть заголовок об `int` не смущает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто используйте дополнительные аргументы функции [setNum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#setNum-9):

```
str.setNum(X, f, 10)
```

И т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Первое. Для числа Пи существует константа M_PI, она живет в `<cmath>`.

Второе. Все ваши числовые константы интерпретируются по стандарту C++ как `int`. Чтобы они были `double`, их надо писать с десятичным нулем на конце - `60.0`

Третье. Тип `double` - это число с ПЛАВАЮЩЕЙ точкой. Его точность на числовой оси неравномерна. Если вам нужна везде равномерная точность, используйте арифметику с фиксированной запятой - например, библиотеку `GMP`

Comment: По поводу второго: замечание справедливое и уместное, но тут оно роли не играет совершенно.

Comment: Ну, тут пока автору везет. А потом он накатает 2 / 5 и будет сильно удивлен.

Comment: Для решения данной задачи тип double подходит, мне не нужно число с фиксированной запятой. Я ошибочно думал, что полученные мною значения с помощью qDebug(), являются истинными значениями переменных. На самом деле когда я преобразую число типа double в строку, оно округляется, и не является истинным значением которое храниться в памяти машины.